# Is there a way to trace or determine which file activates a process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I execute something on the website "save button, reload" or after an interval, A spam of emails are being sent.
on htop I see a series of 
    `smtp -t unix -u -c`
    it is run by user `postfix`

Is there a way for me to see which files activates this commands?

----edit-----
Do you use a specific CMS? Im running ERPNext v8 on the server.
The System does have email features, but I am not using it.
The emails being sent where spam emails.
The Spam emails just started last April,27 and its using too much resources.

Comment: Is the webserver running on your machine (it is not clear).

Comment: Do you mean which process initiated the smtp process?

Comment: sorry for not being clear.. yes the webserver is running on the machine @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: yes, determine which process initiated the smtp @laenkeio

Comment: @user351708 Please [edit] your question to add clarification or information requested in comments. What pages does your web server provide? Do you use a specific CMS? Did you create pages that should send e-mail? Maybe the CMS wants to inform a user or administrator about updates or content changes? Please add more details about the mails that get sent. Does sending mail (to local users and to the internet) work on your system?

Answer (score 0):

With its **-o** flag, [ps](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) returns plenty of information about a process, including :

- command line
- status
- owner
- process ID (aka "PID")
- ...

See the [full list of "ps" format specifiers](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS).

This also includes the PID of the parent of a process aka "PPID".

For instance, to get the PPID of "emacs" running locally (i.e. the PID of the process that started emacs on my workstation), I can run :

```
ps -eo ppid,comm | awk '/emacs/ {print $1}'
```

which returns "1102" (no big deal, but I'll re-use this later). Details of this parent process :

```
ps -o args,comm,state,user 1102
```

or (even better) :

```
ps -o args,comm,state,user $(ps -eo ppid,comm | awk '/emacs/ {print $1}')
```

which returns :

```
COMMAND                     COMMAND         S USER
xfce4-panel --display :0.0  xfce4-panel     S matth
```

NB : the list of fields to display are given just as an example (they are redundant here).